# Derivative of $F: \mathbb{R^{n \times n}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}, A \longmapsto A^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$ denote the space of real $n \times n$ matrics equipped with the matrix norm $\| A \| = \sup_{\| x \lvert\rvert_2 =1} \| Ax \|_2$. Define $$F: \mathbb{R^{n \times n}} \to \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}: A \mapsto A^2$$ Show that $F$ is totally differentiable and compute $DF \, \lvert_A$.

What I've shown is the following: for $H \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$, $$F(A+H)-F(A) = (A+H)^2 - A^2 = AH+HA+H^2$$ So let $T(H) = AH+HA$. Then to show that $T$ is the total derivative, and hence $F$ is totally differentiable, we need to show $$\lim_{H \rightarrow 0} \frac{\| H^2 \|}{\| H \|} = 0$$ My problem is that I'm having difficulty showing this using the matrix norm.

Comment: You may try to prove that $$\|H^2\|\leq\|H\|\|H\|$$

Comment: I suspect you mean "$\lim_{||H|| \rightarrow 0} \dots$".

Comment: @EricTowers Isn't that equivalent to $\lim_{H \rightarrow 0}$ since $\lvert\rvert H \lvert\rvert = 0$ iff $H =0$?

Comment: @Kalypso : This time.  What about next time?  Good habits start with good practice.

Comment: @EricTowers: The terminology $H \to 0$ is fairly standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, one can show

$$\| H^2\| \le \| H\|^2$$

or in general, $\| AB\| \le \|A\| \cdot\|B\|$, where $A, B$ are $n\times n$ matrices.

To calculate $\|AB\|$, let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\|_2 = 1$. Then

$$\|(AB)x\|_2 = \|A (Bx)\|_2.$$

This is zero if $Bx = 0$. If not, then write $Bx = \|Bx\|_2 \frac{Bx}{\|Bx\|_2}$ and so

$$\|(AB)x\|_2 = \|Bx\|_2 \cdot \left\| A \left(\frac{Bx}{\|Bx\|_2}\right)\right\|_2.$$

Since both $x$, $\frac{Bx}{\|Bx\|_2}$ has norm one, we have

$$\|(AB)x\|_2 \le \|B\| \cdot \|A\|.$$

Since this holds for all $x$ with $\|x\|_2 = 1$, by taking supremum we have $\|AB\|\le \|A\| \cdot\|B\|$.

Note that the proof will be a bit easier if you use another (equivalent) definition

$$\|A\| = \sup_{x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.$$